# How to install FSME?

Tags: installation, qt

I am looking to install FSME in Ubuntu, how can I do that. the official doc looks beyond scope - http://fsme.sourceforge.net/doc/install.html

Not sure what step 4 is telling..any suggestions please. (I have installed qt4)

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and then mention as:

```
export QTDIR=/usr/share/qt4
```

And then do `make`.

Comment: I am getting this error -                                          akshayy@ubuntu:~/Desktop/fsme$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
akshayy@ubuntu:~/Desktop/fsme$